# Asp.Net Remove space beteen model property and text

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

(Asp.Net) I'm keeping css properties in database table but when I want to display them in view
like this:

```
style="margin-top: @Model.Settings.MarginTop px;"
```

I have a problem with space between value and px.

Yes I know I can add "px" inside get or write something like this below but I'm sure there is simple way.

```
style="margin: @Html.Encode(Model.Settings.MarginTop)px"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `@()` as shown :-

```
style="margin-top: @(Model.Settings.MarginTop)px;"
```

Comment: @Neel..no brother...if we use @() then it will tell razor engine that it is a razor code and outside it its html ...above answer will work..

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to use string.Format:

```
style="margin-top:@string.Format("{0}px", Model.Settings.MarginTop)"
```